# Xcode 14 shows error projectname.abi.json file missing in intermediates while trying to archive the project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode14

In Xcode 14 I am getting error Abi.json file missing on archive. I am able to run and debug on devices using Xcode 14. Any one knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? I am facing a similar error now.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you accidentally have a class with the same name 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i managed to hack around it.

I was able to copy the abi.json file from derived data created in Debug folder instead of release folder and pasted it in the project file path. Rename it to .abi.json
Then create a build phases script and paste the following Script in there. I placed this script above compile Sources. But you may place it anywhere else.

```
mkdir -p "${CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR}/<ProductName>.build/Objects-normal/arm64/"
cp "${PROJECT_DIR}/<ProductName>.abi.json" "${CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR}/<ProductName>.build/Objects-normal/arm64/<ProductName>.abi.json
```

While archiving this ProductName.abi.json will be renamed to the name it is supposed to be as part of archive step.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these options?
First clean the project.

1. **Delete derived data and run.**
2. **Update to the Latest Package Versions**
3. **Reset Package Caches**

One of the above options must work. Let me know if this works.